# Xdebug remote debugging variable string length

Tags: php, xdebug, elgg

What is the maximum string length for variables' values that Xdebug sends a remote debugging client and can this be altered?

I've only found this in the [documentation](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/display#var_display_max_data):

> xdebug.var_display_max_data Type:
> integer, Default value: 512 Controls
> the maximum string length that is
> shown when variables are displayed
> with either xdebug_var_dump(),
> xdebug.show_local_vars or through
> Function Traces. **This setting does
> not have any influence on the amount
> of data that is send to the client
> through the Remote Debugging
> feature.**

I'm working with code that is building whole HTML documents programmatically (elgg, elglib.php->elgg_view_layout()) and the variable values I need to watch seem to be getting truncated.

I'm running OSX 10.6.7, PHP 5.3.4, Xdebug 2.1.1 installed from PECL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my understanding, it depends on the **debug client** you use.

If your debug client uses the [DGBP](http://www.xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php) protocol of Xdebug 2, it could send

```
feature_set -i <transaction_id> -n max_data -v 2048
```

for example, to negotiate a maximum data length of 2048 bytes for `property_get` commands to initially retrieve (instead of the default length the debug engine would use otherwise).

If the data is larger than 2048 bytes, the debug client could send a `property_value` command to retrieve the entire data.

So technically it should be no problem to alter the maximum length, nor to retrieve the entire data.

The question is, does your debug client send such `feature_set` commands, does it support `property_value` commands and most important, does it allow you to modify the value sent for `max_data` anywhere in its settings/configuration.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  I'm using Netbeans now and have also tried MacGDBp and thought I saw the same issue on each.  After yesterday I'm not so confident though that there wasn't some other issue.  In any case, great answer thanks again.